# Asp.net chart control set width

Tags: asp.net, charts

Good evening,
Right now i am working with Asp.net chart control to draw bar and line chart.
here i facing one problem that i can not set chart width in percentage.
And after long time searching doesn't get any feasible solution.
Here i set chart width in pixel for temporary purpose

```
<asp:Chart ID="Chart2" runat="server" Width="960px">
```

i know that chart width can't b set in % its only in pixel but however i want that my chart width should adjust as the size of browser width.
So is there a feasible solution to achieve this i am eagerly waiting for reply.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have two options to handle this requirment:

1. Make use of the **HttpCapabilitiesBase.ScreenPixelsWidth** property : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpcapabilitiesbase.screenpixelswidth(v=vs.100).aspx
2. Use **jQuery** to dynamically set the width.

   - If you decide to utilize jQuery, here is a link to an existing answer for this:
     [How to make my asp chart scrollable in the x direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22992393/how-to-make-my-asp-chart-scrollable-in-the-x-direction)

Comment: Thanks for reply it helps me in future. but right now my chart has few values so my chart looks very small on screen , so i am looking for solution that fill my chart on screen for few values.